# How many people would not be able to do javascript without jQuery?

Tags: javascript

Do people actually learn the core concepts anymore or are they "learning" from the library? Can you do the basic jQuery actions from scratch, cross browser, YOURSELF? Or would you be lost without $()? Hope this does not get closed. I am curious.

Comment: You should be using jQuery. <g>

Comment: This doesn't belong on SO.  To answer your question: I can do *JavaScript* without a framework, but I can't do **cross-browser** *DOM* without a framework.

Comment: You take the entire universe of JS writers, and then you substract those that can. That should tell you how many can't. ;)

Comment: I dont use raw JS at all, preferring GWT and PyJS over it.

Comment: @Daniel: Really? I can't stand GWT... Nevert tried PyJS, however.

Comment: After one man invented the wheel... why i have to take those big rocks on my back... even worse, why do i have to walk 200kms to lunch...

Answer (score 14):

Could you write a c compiler? How about a web browser in c without using the stdlib?

Could you write a JavaScript engine in assembly? Or machine code?

Libraries, frameworks and languages are there to make our lives easier.

In everything we do in computer science, we stand on the shoulders of giants. Don't forget that, and don't be arrogant about it.

Cheers!

Comment: They make them easier yes. I am not discrediting the frameworks. Arrogance? Try the people who so blindly shot down a question that does not fit into their idea of what programming should be.

Comment: From the FAQ: What kind of questions should I not ask here?

"Avoid asking questions that are subjective, argumentative, or require extended discussion. This is not a discussion board, this is a place for questions that can be answered! "

I assume it got shut down because your question is more of a discussion board type of question.